# Is it possible to limit available tags/functions in Smarty templates?

Tags: smarty

We have a web application (you could say it's a CMS) where we allow users to edit their own templates

We have e.g.:

```
article.template
page.template
```

Now we want to limit what users can or cannot do in their templates. Of course, using PHP will be forbidden (and Smarty allows us to forbid PHP). But is it possible to define what Smarty functions or loops, they can or cannot use?

I cannot find this in the Smarty documentation. We need an easy-to-use template system that can do this.

Comment: I would equate this to driving a car without a steering wheel. How you your going to keep track of people if you have no tracking system  ? Also why is php forbidden ? how else are you going to get the smarty to work ?

Comment: PHP is forbidden because we don't want people to go run do commands or get system info from us. We are only supplying data to the views where users can render it just the way they like it. We use the Zend Framework for everything else

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Smarty version 3: yes, it is possible. Check out [Smarty_Security](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.tpl#advanced.features.security) class.

Note that you also need to limit the HTML they can produce (if their HTML will be viewed by anyone else). I would recommend [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) for this.